# Need to Stop Updating whole view while user scrolling the view SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, view, scrollview, updating

I'm trying to stop updating the view when the user scrolling the view. When user scrolling down to top or top to down, then whole screen updates which blocks the UI for some time. Is there any way to stop updating and when the user stops the scrolling the view automatically updating.

**Code:-**

```
struct Container1: View {

@State private var myDateForDay : String?
@State var items = Array(1...200)
@ObservedObject var data11 = DataClass.sharedInstance

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.init(ColorConstantsName.MainThemeBgColour)
        if myDateForDay == nil {
            Text("No data")
        } else {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        Text(myDateForDay!)
                        ForEach(self.items.indices, id: \.self) { ride in
                            Text("Item \(self.items[ride])")
                        }
                    }.background(GeometryReader {
                        Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,value: -$0.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin.y)
                    }).onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
                        print("offset >> \($0)")
                    }
                }.coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
            }
        }
    }
    .onReceive(self.data11.$myDateByDate) { response in
        print("response = ",response)
        myDateForDay = response
    }
    .onAppear{
        data11.updateValue1()
    }
    }
 }


class DataClass  : NSObject, ObservableObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

@Published var myDateByDate = "" { didSet { self.didChange.send(self) } }

var didChange = PassthroughSubject<DataClass, Never>()

override init() {
    self.myDateByDate = "Starting Data"
}

func updateValue1(){
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+5.0) {
        self.myDateByDate = "Update Date Value"
        self.updateValue12()
    }
}

func updateValue12(){
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+5.0) {
        self.myDateByDate = "Update Date Value222"
        self.updateValue1()
    }
}

static let sharedInstance: DataClass = {
    let instance = DataClass()
    // in case we need to setup up
    return instance
}()

}
```

**Question:** Stop Updating when the user scrolling the view?

Can someone please explain to me how to stop updating the view, I've tried to with above code but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having `@Published` and a `PassthroughSubject` is redundant

Comment: @loremipsum Can you please give me more detail, i'm not understand.

Comment: `didChange` is not required you can remove it. That is the job of `@Published` or `objectWillChange` that is new built in. Creating a `PassthroughSubject` was required in SwiftUI 1.0 and maybe even only in the Betas

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I would also pull out all the code you are currently not using like the `PreferenceKey`. It is hard to tell what is going on here. Also, your `ForEach` shouldn't be using `.indicies` they can be a bit unreliable. `self.items` will work better, and then you use `Text("Item \(ride)")` so the code is a bit cleaner. There are ways of getting the indices if you need them.